# Conditionally Serving a Logo To A Remote Site

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am attempting to create a code snippet for a specific group of people that have earned the right to put our seal on their website.  The idea seemed simple enough at first until I tried to implement it through a different website for testing.

basically i want the user to have a code snippet like:

```
//include jquery for post
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www.mysite.com/jquery.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
    $.post("http://www.mysite.com/test.php", {requesting_id:"12345", requesting_address:window.location.host}, function(data){
    document.write(data);
  });
</script>
```

test.php checks the passed variables against an sql db. If the id they pass matches the web address asking for the file and if we have agreed to continue serving our logo to their page (true/false), it returns the image.

This works great as long as all of the files live on my server.  It appears that the problem has to do with the fact that the php file seems to run not on my server but on the requesting server so the query doesn't run.

Is there a simple way of doing this?  I have spent hours searching for a method and I am out of ideas.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by the "requesting server"?

Comment: Incidentally, your scheme can be easily subverted simply by copying the ID string (which is in plain sight in the HTML/JS).

Comment: http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2010/03/12/making-cross-domain-javascript-requests-using-xmlhttprequest-or-xdomainrequest.html could help

Comment: oli- I know the scheme is inherently flawed but its more to make it a pain then to really secure it.   By "requesting server" I meant the sever that the script users site is served from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use javascript for that and definitely not require all these sites to include jquery.

If you are using php, the easiest thing is to serve an image from a php file. The image would look like:

```
<img src="http://yoursite.com/image.php?request_id=XXXX">
```

and you make a php script that serves an image based on the request_id.

You would have to read an image from your server in php and serve it with a `header("Content-type: image/jpeg")` (in case of a jpeg...).

If you have an image in a variable, the output (for a jpeg...) would simply be something like:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg ($image);
```

Comment: I ended up using pretty much what you suggested... I ran into trouble with the imagejpeg function so I ended up writing the image to a variable with file_get_contents and echoing the variable.

Comment: @DCarr That sounds even simpler, nice!

Answer (score 1):

You would have a script on your side for the jpg that tests the HTTP_REFERRER property.

then the client would simply load:

```
<img src="http://yourweb-site.com/logo.php?id=clientid"/>
```

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-http-referer-variable/

Comment: The HTTP_REFFERER property wasn't consistent so I ended up using javascript to create the image tag and used the window.location.hostname to get my referring host.

Answer (score 0):

as it is written in jQuery's [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

You can use URL like "http://img.example.com/logo?requesting_id=12345..." and simply put image as the output or create iframe...

Answer (score 0):

There are some serious security issues with allowing scripts to operate on objects that live on different domains.  Instead of trying to resolve them on the client side, why not allow the user to place a static URL on their page and you evaluate on the server side whether or not the user is entitled?  If they are, serve the file.   If not, serve a transparent .gif so that their site does not appear to be broken.  Either way you completely avoid any issue with cross-site scripting.

Comment: excellent point!  I got tied up in making things difficult I guess.